# Joomla 500 ISE on every other page but index

Tags: joomla2.5

I'm getting this message on every page but the home page in joomla:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time the error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Apache Server at example.com Port 80

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems other from same webhost having similar issues when a general upgrade of Apache from 2.2 to 2.4 has taken place at their account.

Ref: http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/htaccess-changes/

So you may need to adjust the htaccess to their new setup

Answer (score 0):

Such behaviour often happens when having set 'Use URL rewriting' and you then didn't rename the htaccess.txt to .htaccess

Or you did rename it, but something inside the .htaccess conflicts with your server settings.

Comment: well everything has been the same for months, url rewriting with a .htaccess file, but all of the sudden I start getting this error. I guess it could be possible that godaddy changed something about the server but that seems unlikely. @ot2sen